# Android: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1.01"

Tags: android, numberformatexception

Hi in my app i am reading the values from the database thru cursor and displaying in textview

my cursor contains the value 1.01 now i wanna display 101 in my text view..doing the following

```
TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.acValue);

int ach = Integer.parseInt(topcursor.getString(6));

tv2.setText(ach +"");
```

i am getting the float value as 1.01, now i wanna show the percentage  in textview i.e, 101% .how can i do that

But iam getting numberformatexception. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The value return by your cursor is not an `int`, that's why it's throwing `NumberFormatException`. Try to get it as `String` and convert it the way you want it.

Comment: Try `topcursor.getString(6).replace(".","")`

Comment: why do you want to convert to a Int, instead you can print directly as a string

Comment: As after fetching it from cursor you set it to textview then why converting to integer

Comment: i am getting the float value as 1.01, now i wanna show the percentage  in textview i.e, 101% so how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

`1.01` is not an integer value, that is why the conversion is failing. Also be careful with locale when you use the `parse*` methods

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to parse as it returns the string.

```
TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.acValue);
String mResult  = topcursor.getString(6);
tv2.setText(mResult);
```

Comment: topcursor.getString(6) is a string  does Math.round(String) work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.acValue);

 String ach = topcursor.getString(6);

 tv2.setText(ach);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `replace()` will do the trick

```
TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.acValue);

int ach = Integer.parseInt(topcursor.getString(6).replace(".", ""));

tv2.setText(ach +"%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all ...Did as follows it work fine..

```
float ach = Float.parseFloat(topcursor.getString(6));
String kj = String.valueOf(ach*100+"%");
```

Comment: in your soln,if ach=10.12 the percentage will be 101.2%. Do you want like this or 101% only?

Comment: @krishna ohh yeahhh...i want 101% like this ...please let me know how to do that

Comment: Float ach=(float) Math.round(Float.parseFloat(topcursor.getString(6))*100); tv2.setText(ach +"%");